# What is this geometric pattern called?

Tags: patterns, terminology

[image: background pattern]

What is this background pattern called?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not everything has a name.  I'd just describe it as an interlocking geometric pattern.

Comment: Perhaps geometric basketweave?

Comment: In general, such things would be called a tiling or [tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation).

Answer (score 2):

It is "plane filled with groups of three decorated hexagons".

As you surely know tiling regular hexagons can fill the plane seamlessly. A group of three hexagons can be used, too. With some decorative extras they can be difficult to be seen as hexagons, but I guess that doesn't fool anyone who has drawn something with hexagon based patterns. An example:

[image]

1) and 2) a hexagon and the same rotated 30 degrees. You get version 1 easily in Illustrator by holding Shift-key when you use the polygon tool

3) Three hexagons tiled. You can select one and drag a node with the direct selection tool. The whole shape follows and it snaps perfectly if you have Smart Guides and Snap to Point ON.

4) Three thick lines are drawn from cusps to the center. The strokes are outlined (=Object > Path > Create Outlines)

5) All is selected, the areas are filled with the Shape Builder, extras are deleted (hold ALT to delete unwanted areas with the Shape Builder)

6) More decoration is added, this time black strokes

The parts are grouped to keep them together. Few copies are tiled in the next image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar patterns to this do have some specific names in specific contexts - there are both Japanese and Chinese traditional armours which used this as a scale pattern.
There is a currently in-use architectural interior wall finish using this pattern also, where the central portion of each tile is raised somewhat, adding dimensionality to the basketweave perception - but as already suggested, it's effectively a geometricised basket-weave.

Here's a screengrab of a relatively recently published Substance Source material for use in 3D DCC tools and games - under the name Ancient Chinese Armour; it's pretty clear this is a nod to Chinese Shin Buddhist traditions around the armour worn by a specific figure in that tradition.

[image]

In the Japanese Kumiko design tradition, in which small wooden members are intersected in repeating geometric patterns along the planes of screens, lanterns and woodwork surfaces with no fasteners, using elegant and detailed tongue-and-groove or mortis and pinon connections, there is a specific pattern called Bishamon-kikkou which also bears a striking resemblance to OP's posted image, and it turns out has a similar origin to the "Chinese Armour" as well:

[image]

So these might help OP if they are looking for something with that origin and provenance - but it's still easily described as a geometric basket-weave!

Background:

I know about these two patterns for personal and design reasons - I've spent a lot of time over the years studying traditional Chinese martial arts and their history, and beside having spent a lot of time researching Japanese graphic design and architectural design, I and my family routinely attend a Jodo  Shinshu Buddhist Temple, a tradition which traces its origin directly through the Chinese Shin Buddhist tradition (hence Jodo *Shin*shu).

References:
The screengrab was from my primary 3D modeling machine, using Substance Player to look at a Substance file I purchased from Substance Source.
Link for the Woodworking site from which the second image was pulled:
[Yoshira Wood Works](http://yoshiharawoodworks.com/en/about/kumiko/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This pattern is old i mean seriously old. Same pattern has been known to be usef from africa to the pacific islands by the time europeans came and spoiled everything uip during the colonial period.

Comment: @joojah. Yeah, these type of interlocking patterns or tessellations have been used by many cultures. They also appear in Islamic art, so it's definitely not just a Chinese/Japanese thing.

Comment: **Agreed.** One sees it in *many* decorative and artistic traditions. My intent was not to preclude others, but rather to point out that *although one **can** describe it as a geometric basketweave*, *unlike* many questions we get here with the construction of "what arbitrary or dogmatic style name can describe this loose figurative / abstracted / flattened / geometric graphic element so I can look it up with the googs [most likely to find an obscure example to plagiarize]" where the best answer is "doesn't really have a discrete name nor need one", this *may well* have a specific proper name.